RAID1 device #0 with two NVMe drives not showing while guided partitioning
I have a QNAP TS-262 NAS with two 512GB NVMe SSD disks and two WD Red 8TB HDD disks.
I started installing Debian 12 because I'm not happy with the QNAP OS.
I also combined the two NVMe disks in a RAID1 device #0. But as soon as I select guided partitioning, the RAID1 device #0 is not displayed.
I also tried it with the 8TB disks and a RAID1 device is displayed with them.
I can't explain why it doesn't work or whether I'm doing something wrong.
Does anyone know this problem?

I hope i'am right here.
Thanks for any help

so I've done it now.
I had to select a mount point '/' in the RADI1 device. Then the guided partitioning didn't continue, but I could select apply and continue at the bottom.
I've always found that the whole partitioning process isn't very intuitive. I'm sure some people will disagree with me, but I do it maybe every 5 years and then it's no longer necessary. If you're dealing with it all the time, it's definitely easier.

It's definitely easy when you know what you're doing.
